# SQL query to match rows for a sample attendance management report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've an access log table for attendance management system like this:

```
    ID      LogDate              EmployeeId Direction
    242     2014-05-02 07:59:20.000 2565    in
    1907    2014-05-02 19:00:01.000 2565    out
    3648    2014-05-03 08:08:03.000 2565    in
    5611    2014-05-03 19:32:37.000 2565    out
    5612    2014-05-03 19:33:44.000 2565    out
    7315    2014-05-05 08:01:01.000 2565    in
    9301    2014-05-05 19:37:48.000 2565    out
    10857   2014-05-06 08:29:44.000 2565    in
    12327   2014-05-06 18:51:56.000 2565    out
    14331   2014-05-07 08:44:03.000 2565    in
    16084   2014-05-07 19:09:07.000 2565    out
    17608   2014-05-08 07:58:13.000 2565    in
    21155   2014-05-09 08:12:26.000 2565    in
    22673   2014-05-09 18:42:55.000 2565    out
    24550   2014-05-10 08:13:09.000 2565    in
    26455   2014-05-10 19:02:28.000 2565    out
    30013   2014-05-12 19:07:53.000 2565    out
    31083   2014-05-13 08:00:27.000 2565    in
    31087   2014-05-13 08:02:39.000 2565    in
    33084   2014-05-13 18:58:09.000 2565    out
    35201   2014-05-14 08:31:13.000 2565    in
    37238   2014-05-14 19:10:03.000 2565    out
    39225   2014-05-15 08:47:44.000 2565    in
    40636   2014-05-15 18:59:47.000 2565    out
    42969   2014-05-16 09:58:17.000 2565    in
    42970   2014-05-16 09:58:24.000 2565    in
    42974   2014-05-16 09:58:51.000 2565    in
    44114   2014-05-16 18:49:39.000 2565    out
    44116   2014-05-16 18:50:43.000 2565    out
    46284   2014-05-17 09:07:03.000 2565    in
    47323   2014-05-17 17:56:57.000 2565    out
    48719   2014-05-19 08:05:28.000 2565    in
    49919   2014-05-19 18:52:35.000 2565    out
    51188   2014-05-20 09:02:07.000 2565    in
    52348   2014-05-20 19:01:05.000 2565    out
    54231   2014-05-21 09:35:49.000 2565    in
    55896   2014-05-21 19:57:48.000 2565    out
```

I have the following conditions to get the duration for a sample 12 hours shift log details:

1. Ideal case: Wherein each In and corresponding Out (directions) to be matched and the duration to be calculated by deducting Out-time from In-time
2. In, No-Out, In: Wherein, there is no Out record for the In and it is followed by another In. Display NULL and hence no duration can be calculated, since an Out is missing, let us put 12:00:00 (shift duration).
3. In, Out, Out: The duration should be equal to earliest Out minus latest In.
4. In, Out, In, Out: Duration = First out - First In + second out - second in.

Note: This is for 12 hour shift and note that when there is an in on 20-july-2014 19:00:00 hours, the out might happen on 21-july-2014 07:05:00 and the duration is 12:05:00 hours.

I've written Sqls to get the result, but I'm unable to handle certain conditions:
Here is the [test data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f0f0/1):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tmpAccessLogTbl]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tmpAccessLogTbl]
GO

CREATE TABLE  tmpAccessLogTbl   (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [LogDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Direction] [nvarchar](3) NULL
) 
;



INSERT INTO tmpAccessLogTbl ([ID], [LogDate], [EmployeeId], [Direction])
SELECT 242, '20140502 07:59:20.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 1907, '20140502 19:00:01.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 3648, '20140503 08:08:03.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 5611, '20140503 19:32:37.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 5612, '20140503 19:33:44.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 7315, '20140505 08:01:01.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 9301, '20140505 19:37:48.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 10857, '20140506 08:29:44.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 12327, '20140506 18:51:56.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 14331, '20140507 08:44:03.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 16084, '20140507 19:09:07.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 17608, '20140508 07:58:13.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 21155, '20140509 08:12:26.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 22673, '20140509 18:42:55.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 24550, '20140510 08:13:09.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 26455, '20140510 19:02:28.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 30013, '20140512 19:07:53.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 31083, '20140513 08:00:27.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 31087, '20140513 08:02:39.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 33084, '20140513 18:58:09.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 35201, '20140514 08:31:13.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 37238, '20140514 19:10:03.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 39225, '20140515 08:47:44.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 40636, '20140515 18:59:47.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 42969, '20140516 09:58:17.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 42970, '20140516 09:58:24.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 42974, '20140516 09:58:51.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 44114, '20140516 18:49:39.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 44116, '20140516 18:50:43.000', 2565, N'out' UNION ALL
SELECT 46284, '20140517 09:07:03.000', 2565, N'in' UNION ALL
SELECT 47323, '20140517 17:56:57.000', 2565, N'out'
;


SELECT t.EmployeeId,
       t.AttendanceDate,
       t.InTime,
       CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.InTime, t.OutTime) > 23 THEN NULL
            ELSE t.OutTime
       END  AS OutTime,
       CAST (DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.InTime, t.OutTime) AS VARCHAR) + ':' +  CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, t.InTime, t.OutTime) %60  AS VARCHAR) AS Duration
FROM   (
           SELECT i.EmployeeId,
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR, i.LogDate, 106) AS AttendanceDate,
                  i.LogDate  AS InTime,
                  (
                      SELECT MIN(o.LogDate) AS OutTime
                      FROM   tmpAccessLogTbl o
                      WHERE  o.Direction = 'Out'
                             AND o.EmployeeId = i.EmployeeId
                             AND o.LogDate > i.LogDate
                  )          AS OutTime
           FROM   tmpAccessLogTbl       i
           WHERE  i.Direction = 'In'
       )    AS t
ORDER BY
       t.EmployeeId,
       t.AttendanceDate
```

My results are as follows from this Sql:

```
EmployeeId  AttendanceDate     InTime       OutTime                 Duration
2565    02 May 2014 2014-05-02 07:59:20.000 2014-05-02 19:00:01.000 12:1
2565    03 May 2014 2014-05-03 08:08:03.000 2014-05-03 19:32:37.000 11:24
2565    05 May 2014 2014-05-05 08:01:01.000 2014-05-05 19:37:48.000 11:36
2565    06 May 2014 2014-05-06 08:29:44.000 2014-05-06 18:51:56.000 10:22
2565    07 May 2014 2014-05-07 08:44:03.000 2014-05-07 19:09:07.000 11:25
2565    08 May 2014 2014-05-08 07:58:13.000 NULL                    35:44
2565    09 May 2014 2014-05-09 08:12:26.000 2014-05-09 18:42:55.000 10:30
2565    10 May 2014 2014-05-10 08:13:09.000 2014-05-10 19:02:28.000 11:49
2565    13 May 2014 2014-05-13 08:00:27.000 2014-05-13 18:58:09.000 10:58
2565    13 May 2014 2014-05-13 08:02:39.000 2014-05-13 18:58:09.000 10:56
2565    14 May 2014 2014-05-14 08:31:13.000 2014-05-14 19:10:03.000 11:39
2565    15 May 2014 2014-05-15 08:47:44.000 2014-05-15 18:59:47.000 10:12
2565    16 May 2014 2014-05-16 09:58:17.000 2014-05-16 18:49:39.000 9:51
2565    16 May 2014 2014-05-16 09:58:24.000 2014-05-16 18:49:39.000 9:51
2565    16 May 2014 2014-05-16 09:58:51.000 2014-05-16 18:49:39.000 9:51
2565    17 May 2014 2014-05-17 09:07:03.000 2014-05-17 17:56:57.000 8:49
```

To summarize, I will put the the results of my above Sql and expected results here:

```
                         -- My Current Query  --     --  Expected Results --
Sl  EmpID     Day       InTime  OutTime Duration    InTime  OutTime Duration
1   2565    02-May-2014 7:59    19:00   11:00:41    7:59    19:00   11:00:41
2   2565    03-May-2014 8:08    19:32   11:24:34    8:08    19:32   11:24:34
3   2565    05 May 2014 8:01    19:37   11:36:47    8:01    19:37   11:36:47
4   2565    06 May 2014 8:29    18:51   10:22:12    8:29    18:51   10:22:12
5   2565    07 May 2014 8:44    19:09   10:25:04    8:44    19:09   10:25:04
6   2565    08 May 2014 7:58    NULL    NULL        7:58            12:00:00
7   2565    09 May 2014 8:12    18:42   10:30:29    8:12    18:42   10:30:29
8   2565    10 May 2014 8:13    19:02   10:49:19    8:13    19:02   10:49:19
9   2565    13 May 2014 8:00    18:58   10:57:42            
10  2565    13 May 2014 8:02    18:58   10:55:30    8:02    18:58   10:55:30
11  2565    14 May 2014 8:31    19:10   10:38:50    8:31    19:10   10:38:50
12  2565    15 May 2014 8:47    18:59   10:12:03    8:47    18:59   10:12:03
13  2565    16 May 2014 9:58    18:49   8:51:22         
14  2565    16 May 2014 9:58    18:49   8:51:15         
15  2565    16 May 2014 9:58    18:49   8:50:48     9:58    18:49   8:50:48
16  2565    17 May 2014 9:07    17:56   8:49:54     9:07    17:56   8:49:54
```

In the expected result, whenever there is no out time to corresponding in, the duration should be 12:00:00.

Please help me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be much more useful if you reduce the amount of sample data to a minimal amount. Just show a few rows that allow you to highlight the range of data and allow your problem to be identified as people will be put off reading the question with so much data posted.

Comment: Thanks @Tanner, now input data has been reduced.

Comment: He said a few... there's still about 40-50 rows!

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem with your code is that rows with NULL OutTime values in the output should have a Duration of 12:00:00, the following code should work for you.

What I did was add your CASE statement logic used in the OutTime field calculation to the strings used to generate the Duration field.  Wrapping that calculation in an ISNULL() function means that those values with too long of a duration will return whatever you want.

```
SELECT t.EmployeeId,
       t.AttendanceDate,
       t.InTime,
       CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.InTime, t.OutTime) > 23 THEN NULL
            ELSE t.OutTime
       END  AS OutTime,
       ISNULL(CAST (
         DATEDIFF
          (
            HOUR, 
            t.InTime, 
            CASE 
              WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.InTime, t.OutTime) > 23 
              THEN NULL
              ELSE t.OutTime
            END) AS VARCHAR) 
        + ':' 
        + CAST(
          DATEDIFF
           (
             minute, 
             t.InTime, 
             CASE 
              WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.InTime, t.OutTime) > 23 
              THEN NULL
              ELSE t.OutTime
            END
           ) %60  AS VARCHAR), '12:00') AS Duration
FROM   (
           SELECT i.EmployeeId,
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR, i.LogDate, 106) AS AttendanceDate,
                  i.LogDate  AS InTime,
                  (
                      SELECT MIN(o.LogDate) AS OutTime
                      FROM   tmpAccessLogTbl o
                      WHERE  o.Direction = 'Out'
                             AND o.EmployeeId = i.EmployeeId
                             AND o.LogDate > i.LogDate
                  )          AS OutTime
           FROM   tmpAccessLogTbl       i
           WHERE  i.Direction = 'In'
       )    AS t
ORDER BY
       t.EmployeeId,
       t.AttendanceDate
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f0f0/5)